# What does the patch keyword in Dart do?

Tags: dart

Can someone explain what the patch keyword does? For example, in
`math_patch.dart` I see

```
patch num pow(num x, num exponent) => MathNatives.pow(x, exponent);
patch double atan2(num a, num b) => MathNatives.atan2(a, b);
patch double sin(num x) => MathNatives.sin(x);
patch double cos(num x) => MathNatives.cos(x);
```

What does this mean? What are `_patch.dart` files for?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The patch mechanism is used internally (and is only available
internally, not to end users) to provide different implementations of
core library functionality.

For the math library that you have below, the platform independent
library source in `lib/math` declares these methods as `external`.
`external` methods get their implementation from a patch file. There
is a *patch file* in the VM in `runtime/lib/math_patch.dart`, which
supplies the implementation for the VM and there is a patch file in
the `dart2js` compiler in
`lib/compiler/implementation/lib/math_patch.dart`, which supplies the
`dart2js` implementation.

The `external` keyword is understood by the analyzer and doing it this
way allows only the shared part to be in the SDK and be understood by
the tools. That means that the SDK can have `lib/math` instead of having
`lib/math/runtime` and `lib/math/dart2js`, which makes the SDK cleaner and
easier to understand.