# Meaning of the "patch" keyword in a .dart file

Tags: keyword, standards-compliance, dart

Here is sample in Dart language:

```dart
patch class List<E> {
}
```

This is not patch file because it has extension `.dart` and contains regular source code written in Dart language except for `patch` keyword.

Will be this keyword standardized in future in [TC52 - Dart - Ecma International](http://www.ecma-international.org/memento/TC52.htm)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does the patch keyword in Dart do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12853129/what-does-the-patch-keyword-in-dart-do)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`patch` classes are a VM/compiler feature that are not accessible to normal developers. It is used to share code between the VM and dart2js implementation.

There is no need to standardize the keyword in TC52.